# Android Studio Material Design....styles.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, android-appcompat

I want to use the AppTheme android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar for my app. This is available from SDK 21...My minimum SDK is 16. I have the support library com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0 in my build gradle file. I want to create a second styles file under the the values folder. I want to have two styles files...one for Lollipop...greyed out version 22 next to it...and one for pre Lollipop. How to do this?

Answer (score 7):

As said create a values folder for a specific Api Level

```
res/values-v21/styles.xml
res/values/styles.xml
```

In `values/styles.xml` create to styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
</style>
```

In `values-v21/styles.xml` create to styles:

```
<!-- Themes for Android API21 -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
</style>
```

Inside your `AndroidManifest.xml` you should use `AppTheme` as your global application theme

Further you should use the `Toolbar` from the SupportLibary instead of the default Actionbar. This is why the Base Theme sets the Actionbar to false

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the other answers you can use different styles.xml file in different folders.

I would like to add an option to other answers.

You can define a Base Style used by each versions, and customize singles attributes.

In `res/values/styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
   <!-- custom pre-Lollipop attributes -->
</style>
```

In `res/values-v21/styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
   <!-- custom Lollipop attributes -->
</style>
```

Finally use the `AppTheme` in your Activity (you have to use a ` [ActionBarActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html)).

Answer (score 2):

Create two styles.xml files in different folders, e.g:

```
res/values-v21/styles.xml
res/values/styles.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add another folder called "values-v21" in your "res" directory. Then create a "styles.xml" within that directory for your Lollipop styles.